# EC2 instance /var wiped out after stop/start

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-opsworks

I'm using OpsWorks to manage my application instances. I have one Load Based EBS-backed instance that starts when load is high and stops when it's low. However, after instance is stopped and started again contents of /var is completely removed. `df -h` shows:

```
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  2.2G  5.4G  29% /
udev            3.7G   12K  3.7G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  188K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       414G  199M  393G   1% /mnt
```

so /var is not on ephemeral storage. Why?

Comment: Are you sure its getting stopped/started and not terminated/launched? If you are using autoscaling, the behavior is to terminate and launch new instances on scaling actions.

Comment: I've just answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that one of opsworks default recipes is mounting something (`/mnt/var/www`) to this folder. Solution was to use some other folder instead `/var/www`.